# How can I load a list of items in an Ansible playbook task

Tags: list, yaml, jinja2, ansible

I have a file `ansible/group_vars/test_dir/whitelist.yml` which contains:

```
list:
[item1, item2, item3]
```

How can I have this list in a YAML style? like:

```
list:
- item1
- item2
- item3
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution. I managed to create a template:

```
my_list:
{% for item_of_interest in curl_command.result %}
- {{item_of_interest.attribute}}
{% endfor %}
```

the curl_command.result is actually a variable that I register in the task where I want to make use of this list... but for now, this did it for me.